# Titanium SDK 5.4.0.GA is showing too many logs at console on Android platform

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

did anyone notice that on Android - Ti SDK 5.4.0.GA is showing many output at console on all modes like Trace, Debug, Info, Warning, Error.

I have not tried it for Wi-Fi off state, but it is showing such lines every second when the device is connected to Wi-Fi and my console filled up with 100 lines in just few seconds:

```
[INFO] :   D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController( 1166): getNumberOfActiveSim:0
[INFO] :   D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController( 1166): getPhoneSignalIconList: mMaxLevelOfSignalStrengthIndicator = 4 inetCondition = 0
[INFO] :   D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController( 1166): getDataSignalIconId: mMaxLevelOfSignalStrengthIndicator = 4 inetCondition = 0 iconLevel = 4
[INFO] :   D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController( 1166): updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=4
```

Can anyone suggest any solution as this is getting quite annoying and I cannot focus on the console output from code due to too many above logs?

Comment: JIRA ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4548

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Finally I found a solution to this problem:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/8754
Logs that contain a dot (or any other character besides letters) won't be caught in the `don't show` part!

The PR will change the RegEx rule to match any character.

**Old solution:**

Check the output of `ti config cli.logLevel` and set it to `info`
Might solve the problem for you.

I'm facing the same issue and I use `monitor` with this custom filter:

```
^(?!(WifiStateMachine|WIFI_UT|AppOps|GraphicsStats|RegisteredNfcid2Cache|Wifi|NotifUtils|WIFI|usbnet|Ethernet|FaceDetectTask|RecentsTaskLoadPlan|MorningBundlePlugin|SocialManagerService|PhoneApp|LoadDialerReceiver|Icing|Herrevad|Finsky|StatusBarManagerService|DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService|ClearcutLoggerApiImpl|AlarmManager|GCoreUlr|GCoreFlp|APSAnalyticsService|QCNEJ|NetworkStats|IpReachabilityMonitor|Nfcid2RoutingManager|ls|WifiManager|libc|dex2oat|ACRA|HtcMirrorLinkAmsListener|LOWI-Scan|DownloadManagerWrapper|wpa_supplicant|QCALOG|WIFI_ICON|HtcWrapCustomizationManager|gdlights|PowerUtils|ExtremePowerSave|WifiService|FrameworkListener|MediaRouterServie|DotMatrix|PowerUI|PMS|XTCC-5.1.0.7|NetworkManagement|HtcPowerSaver|BatteryControlle|NetLinkSocketObs|WifiController|NetlinkSocketObs|BatteryService|UsbnetService|DeviceIdleControler|Keyboard.Facilit|xiaomi|qdlights|SensorService|AutoSetting|HtcWifiRssiMonitor|HtcWifiDataStallTracker|WifiAutoJoinController|HtcWLD_v5.1.0|WifiMonitor|WifiConfigStore|StatusBar.NetworkController|CwMcuSensor|BrcmNfcJni|DATA_ICON|TelephoneCallback|ContactMessageStore|HtcUPManager|ScreenOnOffReceiver|DeviceIdleController|QSPanel|NetworkPolicy|GpsLocationProvider|SensorManager|SmartNS_PSService|PhoneStatusBar|ScrimController|Settings|LocationManagerService|getVisibilityByRssi|NetworkController.WifiSignalController|GAv4|IntegrityChecker|KernelCpuSpeedReader|KernelWakelockReader|BatteryStatsImpl|WeatherUtility|WeatherTimeKeeper|PNP_UPDATERD|DsService|PathParser|StatusBarManagerServiceHtcASN_1.1|SignalClusterView|SIGNAL_ICON|HtcSystemUPManager|ConnectivityService|HtcASN_1.1|SignalClusterView|SIGNAL_ICON|HtcSystemUPManager|ConnectivityService|WSP|Babel|CityCodeHelper|TetherStatsReporting|TelephonyCallback))
```

Put this in `by Log Tag` in a new filter. My device is a HTC A9, a very log-noisy device!

If you still see rows you don't want to just put attach the tags with `|tagname`

Comment: These logs are showing on every Log level as I mentioned in my question.

Can we not make some changes in SDK to remove these logs???

Comment: If you haven't already done that you should file a bug at JIRA (http://jira.appcelerator.org/) to get that fixed.